# Collecting bags to go thru customs?

Tags: customs-and-immigration

If traveling from Rio de Janeiro to São Paulo and then connecting to Buenos Aires Argentina, do I need to collect my bags in São Paulo before boarding for Buenos Aires?

Comment: Did you book separate flights? Do you have to change airports?

Comment: To be more precise, are the flights on the same ticket/booking?